# Count after filtering/joining two tables

Tags: postgresql, count, inner-join

I think I am missing something obvious or otherwise on the wrong path here. I am using postgresql (new to it).

I have two tables:

TABLE A:

| id | age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 55 |
| 3 | 65 |
| 4 | 75 |
| 5 | 85 |

TABLE B:

| id | service1 | service2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | Yes |
| 2 | Yes | No |
| 3 | Yes | Yes |
| 4 | Yes | Yes |
| 5 | No | Yes |

I want to get the count of all customers over the age of `55` with service1 and service2.

When I use the code below, I get the correct list of customers, but doing a select count(*) does not give me a total, but rather count per each id.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B on A.id = B.id
WHERE A.age > 54
AND B.service1 = 'Yes'
AND B.service2 = 'Yes'
GROUP BY A.id, B.id;
```

I am looking for a total count but I end up with something like this:

|  | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

I am sure this has been answered many times but I am having a hard time searching and finding it. I am new to this, so my google skills are not up to par yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One canonical approach here uses aggregation over the entire joined tables:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b
    ON b.id = a.id
WHERE b.service1 = 'Yes' AND b.service2 = 'Yes' AND
      a.age > 55;
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for the prompt response. I thought you had to use 'group by' every time you did joins. I've got a lot to learn!